# FileUtils.write writing speed

Tags: java, mysql, apache, performance, apache-commons-io

I am trying to read from mysql and write the result into a txt file. As you can see I use Apache's Commons IO. Result set contains tweets and every sql query below nearly returns 725 rows to be writed into txt file. My problem is the writing speed, it is very slow (2-3 kb per second). Am I missing something here?

```
Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
        for (int week = 0 ; week<hashTag.length/15 ; week++){

            File container = new File("C:\\Users\\COMP\\Desktop\\threeMonthsSplitTxt\\weeklyBinsTwitter\\week"+week+"-"+hashTag[week]+".txt");

            for(int hash = 0 ; hash<15 ; hash++){
                ResultSet results = stmt2.executeQuery("select tweetContent
                    from threemonthswithhashtag
                    where hashTag = '"+hashTag[hashCount]+"'
                      and tweetCreatedTime between '"+firstDate[hashCount]+"'
                                               and '"+ lastDate[hashCount]+"';");

                while(results.next()){
                    tweetContent = results.getString("tweetContent");
                    try{
                        FileUtils.write(container,newLine,"UTF8",true);
                        FileUtils.write(container,tweetContent,"UTF8",true);
                    }catch(IOException e){e.getMessage();}
                }
                hashCount++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an API that will create/open/close a file (handle) for **each** write operation.

And you are surprised that this doesn't give you optimal performance?!

That utility method might be convenient, but heck, instead of going

```
loop:
  try:
    open file; write to file; close file
    open file; write to file; close file
```

Consider doing something along the lines of

```
open file
loop:
  try:
    write to open file
    write to open file
close file
```

instead. Of course, that means that you will have to write *more* code; making things more complicated; but well: one has to balance "super-easy to read" code with "performing good enough" code sometimes.

Probably the most rework could go even go like:

```
StringBuilder toWrite = ...
loop:
  try:
  toWrite.append(...)
  toWrite.append(...)
```

and then, after the loop, you use `FileUtils.write()` in order to simply write the whole content (that you collected within memory) **in one** single shot to the file system.

That should keep the overall complexity of your new code at a reasonable level; but help with better end-to-end performance.

Comment: _And you are surprised that this doesn't give you optimal performance?!_ - This comment does not contribute to your answer at all.

Comment: It has been a long time since I did file operations on Java so now I see the noob mistake. But at that time using commons seemed reasonable. How can I implement your suggestion? Is there any way to do it with commons or should I use another method?

Comment: @Aaron Clifton Just use an `FileOutputStream` rather than a `File` and use `IOUtils.write(fos, content, "UTF8");`

Comment: @GhostCat nope max file size is about 3 mb each. But I will have 315 of them. Ok I will try that fix.

Comment: @AaronClifton My idea should work fine then. If not, davidxxx gave you good enough hints too ;-)